# Can you Dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10?

Tags: dual-boot

I kind new to Ubuntu and installed 12.04 LTS to get an old Pentium run computer from the grave. now i want to try out 12.10 and soon enough get my other computer to run it.

Comment: 12.04 is LTS meaning it will be supported for long time (~ 5years).. if u want functionality then it is suggested that u only keep with 12.04..  and ya its not recommended to dual boot for an intelligent option to try the OS will be to use virtualization. I suggest you to use Oracle VirtualBox. good luck

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can! You only have to install them on separate partitions and set your grub accordingly.

If your goal is testing purposes, you can install one Ubuntu a virtual machine

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can dual boot multiple Ubuntu's on one machine.

Use the "Something Else" option on the installer to manually select the partition to install to.